# how to test react-select with react-testing-library

Tags: reactjs, integration-testing, react-select, react-testing-library

App.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Select from "react-select";

const SELECT_OPTIONS = ["FOO", "BAR"].map(e => {
  return { value: e, label: e };
});

class App extends Component {
  state = {
    selected: SELECT_OPTIONS[0].value
  };

  handleSelectChange = e => {
    this.setState({ selected: e.value });
  };

  render() {
    const { selected } = this.state;
    const value = { value: selected, label: selected };
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <div data-testid="select">
          <Select
            multi={false}
            value={value}
            options={SELECT_OPTIONS}
            onChange={this.handleSelectChange}
          />
        </div>
        <p data-testid="select-output">{selected}</p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

App.test.js

```
import React from "react";
import {
  render,
  fireEvent,
  cleanup,
  waitForElement,
  getByText
} from "react-testing-library";
import App from "./App";

afterEach(cleanup);

const setup = () => {
  const utils = render(<App />);
  const selectOutput = utils.getByTestId("select-output");
  const selectInput = document.getElementById("react-select-2-input");
  return { selectOutput, selectInput };
};

test("it can change selected item", async () => {
  const { selectOutput, selectInput } = setup();
  getByText(selectOutput, "FOO");
  fireEvent.change(selectInput, { target: { value: "BAR" } });
  await waitForElement(() => getByText(selectOutput, "BAR"));
});
```

This minimal example works as expected in the browser but the test fails.  I think the onChange handler in  is not invoked.  How can I trigger the onChange callback in the test?  What is the preferred way to find the element to fireEvent at?  Thank you

Answer (score 30, accepted):

This got to be the most asked question about RTL :D

The best strategy is to use [`jest.mock`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/jest-object#jestmockmodulename-factory-options) (or the equivalent in your testing framework) to mock the select and render an HTML select instead.

For more info on why this is the best approach, I wrote something that applies to this case too. The OP asked about a select in Material-UI but the idea is the same.

[Original question](https://spectrum.chat/react-testing-library/help/material-ui-textfield-select-non-native%7E70ee0199-7cca-49df-80bd-aa3440e51798) and my answer:

> Because you have no control over that UI. It's defined in a 3rd party module.
>
> So, you have two options:
>
> You can figure out what HTML the material library creates and then use container.querySelector to find its elements and interact with it. It takes a while but it should be possible. After you have done all of that you have to hope that at every new release they don't change the DOM structure too much or you might have to update all your tests.
>
> The other option is to trust that Material-UI is going to make a component that works and that your users can use. Based on that trust you can simply replace that component in your tests for a simpler one.
>
> Yes, option one tests what the user sees but option two is easier to maintain.
>
> In my experience the second option is just fine but of course, your use-case might be different and you might have to test the actual component.

This is an example of how you could mock a select:

```
jest.mock("react-select", () => ({ options, value, onChange }) => {
  function handleChange(event) {
    const option = options.find(
      option => option.value === event.currentTarget.value
    );
    onChange(option);
  }
  return (
    <select data-testid="select" value={value} onChange={handleChange}>
      {options.map(({ label, value }) => (
        <option key={value} value={value}>
          {label}
        </option>
      ))}
    </select>
  );
});
```

You can read more [here](https://www.polvara.me/posts/testing-a-custom-select-with-react-testing-library/).

Comment: @GiorgioPolvara-Gpx While I get the approach you are suggesting I am curious to know if that goes actually against the guiding principles of Testing Library. The lib encourages to test what the final user actually interacts with (so to me is more an integration/functional test rather that an unit test). In your approach you are mocking the external dependency (which is good for a unit test) but if the dependency gets updated there is the change to have a successful test on a failing software. What are your thoughts about it?

Comment: @GiorgioPolvara-Gpx I read your blog and I'm using the `react-select/async` so I used `jest.mock("react-select/async",...` but I get a **Unable to find an element by: [data-testid="select"]** when trying `fireEvent.change(getByTestId("select"), { target: { value: "foo" } });` I have a `render(<MySearchEngine />)` and it's like the getByTestId is looking into it instead of the `jest.mock` block. What have I missed ? thx

Comment: It looks like you're either not mocking correctly or not rendering the select. Have you tried to run `debug()` to see what's on the page?

Comment: One should have absolutely no confidence in their component's test if they mock the component to this extent. I highly recommend NOT going with this approach. You're testing a completely different component in this situation.

Comment: It's a tradeoff between ease of testing and coverage. If your application is for 90% the select don't mock it. But, if you only use the select in some of your pages I don't think spending the time to figure out how to test the select is worth it. Of course ymmv

Comment: I replaced `jest.mock("react-select/async",...` with `jest.mock("../Shared/LocalitySelect.jsx",...` `LocalitySelect.jsx` being my component that renders the react-select/async component itself. Not sure I'm on the right track here but I now get `TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined` at the beginning of `{loadOptions.map(({ label, value }) => (` Now how/where do I populate `loadOptions` if that makes any sense ?...

Comment: It's hard for me to help you from here. Open a new question either here or on the official Spectrum page

Comment: @GiorgioPolvara-Gpx i disagree that you should mock the third party library. if that library changes/breaks, i want to know about it (without necessarily reading the changelog/release notes), and tests are how that is going to happen.

Comment: polvara.me/posts/testing-a-custom-select-with-react-testing-library/

Comment: Another big downside of this approach is that it will force you to always have a label and a value in all components, even if your domain model does not require it... This way should not be taken

Answer (score 55):

In my project, I'm using react-testing-library and jest-dom. 
I ran into same problem - after some investigation I found solution, based on thread: https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/issues/400

Notice that the top-level function for render has to be async, as well as individual steps.

There is no need to use focus event in this case, and it will allow to select multiple values.

Also, there has to be async callback inside getSelectItem.

```
const DOWN_ARROW = { keyCode: 40 };

it('renders and values can be filled then submitted', async () => {
  const {
    asFragment,
    getByLabelText,
    getByText,
  } = render(<MyComponent />);

  ( ... )

  // the function
  const getSelectItem = (getByLabelText, getByText) => async (selectLabel, itemText) => {
    fireEvent.keyDown(getByLabelText(selectLabel), DOWN_ARROW);
    await waitForElement(() => getByText(itemText));
    fireEvent.click(getByText(itemText));
  }

  // usage
  const selectItem = getSelectItem(getByLabelText, getByText);

  await selectItem('Label', 'Option');

  ( ... )

}
```

Comment: I personally prefer this solution much more than the accepted answer, because you keep things like they are. On that way you really test things like they would be tested by a user. If you mock `react-select` you even need to test your own mock, which is somehow counterproductive.. also if you use more complex properties which `react-select` provides your mock also gets more complex and also hard to maintain IMHO

Comment: This answer works well and doesn't require mocks. Thanks!

Comment: Have you gotten this to work with ant 4? I had a similar solution that worked well, but after upgrading it fails to find the option..

Comment: Although I don't see the other solution as intrinsically wrong, I also prefer this solution as it would be closer to the real-world scenario. Thanks for sharing this, this helped me and my colleague solve something we were bumping our heads against for a while with no success in simulating the selection.

Comment: Appreciate this solution! Using the new `screen` import from '@testing-library/react', this can be simplified even further:

(tried to show the function, but comment formatting doesn't really allow for it)

Comment: Just outstanding solution. 
By the way the waitforElement() is now deprecated. I did it like:
`await screen.findByText(itemText);`

Comment: This answer should be the solution.

Comment: await selectItem('Label', 'Option'); what I need to pass in Label and Option ?

Comment: I think, mocking is a better option for a simple use, as we should be __ that react-select covered with tests on their side.

Answer (score 29):

Finally, there is a library that helps us with that: https://testing-library.com/docs/ecosystem-react-select-event. Works perfectly for both single select or select-multiple:

From `@testing-library/react` docs:

```
import React from 'react'
import Select from 'react-select'
import { render } from '@testing-library/react'
import selectEvent from 'react-select-event'

const { getByTestId, getByLabelText } = render(
  <form data-testid="form">
    <label htmlFor="food">Food</label>
    <Select options={OPTIONS} name="food" inputId="food" isMulti />
  </form>
)
expect(getByTestId('form')).toHaveFormValues({ food: '' }) // empty select

// select two values...
await selectEvent.select(getByLabelText('Food'), ['Strawberry', 'Mango'])
expect(getByTestId('form')).toHaveFormValues({ food: ['strawberry', 'mango'] })

// ...and add a third one
await selectEvent.select(getByLabelText('Food'), 'Chocolate')
expect(getByTestId('form')).toHaveFormValues({
  food: ['strawberry', 'mango', 'chocolate'],
})
```

Thanks https://github.com/romgain/react-select-event for such an awesome package!

Comment: works like a charm, eve with Formik and chakra-ui embedded react-select

Comment: good stuff react-select-event, I've been struggling with testing react-select properly

Comment: `react-select` is an awesome package if you want something out of the box. Unfortunately, accessibility and testing are painful. Also, it brings emotion to the project, which is not light, Switched to `downshift` a year ago and will never look back. It requires a little setup, but the result is lighter, easier to test, and accessible out of the box.

Comment: @Constantin I costumized it without using emotion, just normal CSS modules

Answer (score 15):

Similar to @momimomo's answer, I wrote a small helper to pick an option from `react-select` in TypeScript.

Helper file:

```js
import { getByText, findByText, fireEvent } from '@testing-library/react';

const keyDownEvent = {
    key: 'ArrowDown',
};

export async function selectOption(container: HTMLElement, optionText: string) {
    const placeholder = getByText(container, 'Select...');
    fireEvent.keyDown(placeholder, keyDownEvent);
    await findByText(container, optionText);
    fireEvent.click(getByText(container, optionText));
}
```

Usage:

```
export const MyComponent: React.FunctionComponent = () => {
    return (
        <div data-testid="day-selector">
            <Select {...reactSelectOptions} />
        </div>
    );
};
```

```js
it('can select an option', async () => {
    const { getByTestId } = render(<MyComponent />);
    // Open the react-select options then click on "Monday".
    await selectOption(getByTestId('day-selector'), 'Monday');
});
```

Comment: I like this answer most, no need to install extra packages is always a plus

Comment: this does not work with the latest react-select

Comment: This is why I don't like testing-library's philosophy. I'd rather just use Enzyme-Mocha properly

Answer (score 5):

An easy way to test is by doing what the user should do

- Click on the select field.
- Click on one of the items in the dropdown list.

```
function CustomSelect() {

  const colourOptions = [
    { value: 'orange', label: 'Orange', color: '#FF8B00' },
    { value: 'yellow', label: 'Yellow', color: '#FFC400' }
  ]

  return <Select 
    aria-label="my custom select" 
    options={colourOptions}
    //... props  
  />
}
```

```
import { act, render, screen } from '@testing-library/react'; 
import userEvent from '@testing-library/user-event';
// another imports

test('show selected item...', async () => {
  const { getByText, getByLabelText } = render(<CustomSelect />);

  expect(getByText('Orange')).not.toBeInTheDocument();
  
  const myCustomSelect = getByLabelText(/my custom select/i);
  await act(async () => userEvent.click(myCustomSelect));

  const selectedItem = getByText('Orange');
  await act(async () => userEvent.click(selectedItem));

  expect(getByText('Orange')).toBeInTheDocument();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

In case you are not using a `label` element, the way to go with `react-select-event` is:

```
const select = screen.container.querySelector(
  "input[name='select']"
);

selectEvent.select(select, "Value");
```

Answer (score 1):

Because I wanted to test a component that wrapped `react-select`, mocking it with a regular `<select>` element wouldn't have worked.  So I ended up using the same approach that [the package's own tests](https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select/blob/master/packages/react-select/src/__tests__/Select.test.tsx) use, which is supplying a `className` in props and then using it with `querySelector()` to access the rendered element in the test:

```js
const BASIC_PROPS: BasicProps = {
  className: 'react-select',
  classNamePrefix: 'react-select', 
  // ...
};

let { container } = render(
  <Select {...props} menuIsOpen escapeClearsValue isClearable />
);
fireEvent.keyDown(container.querySelector('.react-select')!, {
  keyCode: 27,
  key: 'Escape',
});
expect(
  container.querySelector('.react-select__single-value')!.textContent
).toEqual('0');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
export async function selectOption(container: HTMLElement, optionText: string) {
  let listControl: any = '';
  await waitForElement(
    () => (listControl = container.querySelector('.Select-control')),
  );
  fireEvent.mouseDown(listControl);
  await wait();
  const option = getByText(container, optionText);
  fireEvent.mouseDown(option);
  await wait();
}
```

NOTE: 
container: container for select box ( eg: container = getByTestId('seclectTestId') )

Comment: where did `await wait()` come from?

Comment: wait() is from react testing library only.
better if we combine fireEvent in act ().

Comment: fireEvent doesn't need to be wrapped in act()

Answer (score 0):

This solution worked for me.

```
fireEvent.change(getByTestId("select-test-id"), { target: { value: "1" } });
```

Hope it might help strugglers.

Comment: `react-select` doesn't pass any `data-testid`  to any of its children elements, and you can't do so by providing it by yourself. Your solution works for regular `select` HTML elements, but I'm afraid it won't work for `react-select` lib.

Comment: @StanleySathler correct, this will not work for `react-select`, but only an HTML `select`

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution which worked for my use case and requires no react-select mocking or separate library (thanks to [@Steve Vaughan](https://spectrum.chat/users/stevethatcodes)) found on the [react-testing-library spectrum chat.](https://spectrum.chat/testing-library/general/approaches-to-testing-components-that-use-react-select%7E85e86e37-9fdb-480f-8cba-217096414719?m=MTU0OTQ2MDYwOTYzMQ==)

The downside to this is we have to use `container.querySelector` which RTL advises against in favour of its more resillient selectors.

Answer (score 0):

if for whatever reason there is a label with the same name use this

```
const [firstLabel, secondLabel] = getAllByLabelText('State');
    await act(async () => {
      fireEvent.focus(firstLabel);
      fireEvent.keyDown(firstLabel, {
        key: 'ArrowDown',
        keyCode: 40,
        code: 40,
      });

      await waitFor(() => {
        fireEvent.click(getByText('Alabama'));
      });

      fireEvent.focus(secondLabel);
      fireEvent.keyDown(secondLabel, {
        key: 'ArrowDown',
        keyCode: 40,
        code: 40,
      });

      await waitFor(() => {
        fireEvent.click(getByText('Alaska'));
      });
    });
```

or If you have a way to query your section—for example with a data-testid—you could use within:

```
within(getByTestId('id-for-section-A')).getByLabelText('Days')
within(getByTestId('id-for-section-B')).getByLabelText('Days')
```

Answer (score 0):

To anyone out there - I got mine to select by doing fireEvent.mouseDown on the option instead of click.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I used react-select with react-testing-library and redux-form, faced various issues in the different methods I tried, the only one that worked:

```
  // target the <input/> of your element
  const dropdown = screen.getByTestId('my-select-test-id').querySelector('input')

  // opens up the options, notice the "mousedown" event
  fireEvent(
    dropdown,
    new MouseEvent('mousedown', {
      bubbles: true,
      cancelable: true,
    })
  )

  const dropdownOption = await screen.findByText('my option text')

  // selects the option we want, notice again the "mousedown" event
  fireEvent(
    dropdownOption,
    new MouseEvent('mousedown', {
      bubbles: true,
      cancelable: true,
    })
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried the following mock, and it has worked for me.

```
jest.mock('react-select', () => {
  return {
    __esModule: true,
    default: jest.fn((props) => (
      <div
        data-testid={props['data-testid']}
        data-props={JSON.stringify({
          ...props,
          placeholder: expect.anything(),
        })}
      />
    )),
  }
})
```